# Eigenvalues of $A^2-2I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be a 3x3 matrix such that $tr(A)=3$ and $|A|=2$. If 1 is an eigenvalue of A then what are the eigenvalues of the matrix $A^2-2I$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we are given
x+y=2
xy=2

Now we can find x,y which give other two e-vals of A. then e-values of $A^2-2I$ are:

$x^2$-2,$y^2$-2 and -1

Answer (score 1):

You can determine all the eigenvalues of A before you even look at the second expression. One eigenvalue is 1. The trace equals the sum:

$$1+x+y=3$$
The determinant equals the product
$$xy=2$$

Solve this, and then you just plug them into the second expression, which obviously has eigenvalues $x^2-2,y^2-2,-1$.